# How do you properly close a UIWebView inside a UIPopover when ARC is enabled

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uipopovercontroller

I have an `UIPopoverController` containing an `UIWebViewController` that is opened by a button press. Pressing the button while open calls `dismissPopoverAnimated:animated:`

I keep getting

```
*** -[_UIWebViewScrollView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x21cb01b0.
```

snippet from button press code:

```
if ([self.popover isPopoverVisible]){
    CCLOG(@"Calling dismissPopoverAnimated");
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popover = nil;
    }
```

The `dealloc` method of this class is as follows:

```
-(void) dealloc {
  [self.webView stopLoading];
  [self.webView.scrollView setDelegate:nil];
  self.webView.delegate = nil;
  self.webView = nil;
}
```

Comment: This was actually caused by a third party library and not related to the UIPopover code.

Answer (score 0):

There is something that it is not entirely clear to me... you are using ARC, but at the same time you are also providing a `dealloc` method. Possibly this is the reason why a double release occurs. Would you try removing the `self.webView = nil;` statement from `dealloc`?

Comment: I tried that but then the UIPopovers' dealloc method does not get called when you dismiss the popover. This does not fix the issue it only delays it so that it occurs when you press the button again, in the next alloc/init phase it deallocs the old and sets the pointer to the new. The crash still happens.